# Elasticsearch Bulk Response

Tags: elasticsearch, response, bulk

I am using KAFKA-connect-Elasticsearch to index much data.But I can see much messages backup,I am doubting the speed of ES response is slow.So I wanna figure out **at which stage does the BulkResponse corresponding to BulkRequest occur/** Which step does this response specifically refer to before returning? Does it mean that the request was successfully written to the translog and flushed to disk? Or the requset becomes the segment in the os cache?Looking forward to your reply very much.

I wanna figure out at which stage does the BulkResponse corresponding to BulkRequest occur.